# How do you make Test and Code Coverage publicly available

Tags: azure-devops

How do you make Test and Code Coverage from the Azure Devops publicly available, so (anonymous, without an MSDN account) users can see the results without having to have an account on your organization? I tried fiddling with the "Readers" settings within Azure DevOps but no luck. Typically, when users don't have an account the Code Coverage will load indefinitely and the Test tab is not shown.

Question 2: how can I provide a direct link (url) to my latest code-coverage for a specific build definition? Using Shield.io i was able to get a badge for the code-coverage but i also would like to provide a direct link to the report.

shields.io link to badge: https://img.shields.io/azure-devops/coverage/OffTheRecordv4/OTRv4/1

This is the project:
https://dev.azure.com/OffTheRecordv4/OTRv4/_build?definitionId=1&_a=summary

and the shield.io badge can be viewed here:
https://github.com/southernsun/otr

when logged in: 
[image: when logged in]

When logged out (spinning wheel never stops and nothing loads):
[image: when logged out]

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

I created a feature request, feel free to support the request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1069707/allow-code-coverage-and-test-plan-tabs-accessible.html

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you are working with a **public project**. A public project allows non-members of a project and users who aren't signed in read-only, limited access to the project's artifacts and services. Check the following table:

[image]

To contribute to a public project, you must be added as a member of that project and assigned either Stakeholder, Basic, or Basic + Test Plans access. The access level determines the user interfaces you can access. If you want users to access Test, you would need to assign Basic + Test Plans access to them.

Regarding how to get code coverage link, you may try [Code Coverage - Get Build Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API, which would give you `codeCoverageFileUrl` in response.

Comment: You would imagine that all facets of the Pipeline (build and release) would be read-only, including Code Coverage and Test Coverage. But ok, so this is not possible by default. I will see if i can log a ticket with Microsoft to give some insight in whether there is any timeline for this...

Comment: I created a feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1069707/allow-code-coverage-and-test-plan-tabs-accessible.html